# Taking derivative under the integral sign

Tags: integration, derivatives

Reading a textbook and stuck on this one detail... would like to confirm my understanding.

The book defines a function $\eta \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$, $0 \leq \eta^\prime \leq 2$, $\eta(t) = 0$ for $t \leq 1$, $\eta(t) =1$ for $t \geq 2$. It then claims that the following function $w_\epsilon(x)$ is clearly $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$:
\begin{equation}
w_\epsilon(x) = \int_\Omega \Gamma(x-y) \eta\left(\frac{\vert x-y \vert}{\epsilon} \right) f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{equation} 
where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation, $\Gamma = C \vert x - y \vert^{2-n}$, and $f$ is a bounded integrable function.

I just want to confirm the reasoning behind this function being $C^1$ is because the integrand taken together is continuously differentiable in $x$ (because $\Gamma$ is continuously differentiable everywhere $x \neq y$ and when $x=y$, $\eta = 0$ for all $\epsilon$). Does it not matter that $\Gamma$ is undefined when $x=y$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp - right, but then $\Gamma(x-y)$ is undefined when $x=y$, so we have something undefined multiplied by 0, isn't that a problem?

Comment: When $x\to y$ then $\Gamma(x-y)\eta(|x-y|/\epsilon)\to 0$.

Comment: $\eta(|x-y|/\epsilon)=0$ everywhere over the near approach of $x$ to $y$, so the discontinuity of the gamma term is not a problem.

Comment: @GrahamKemp - ok, that makes sense, I guess I thought that since differentiability is a pointwise property, it would somehow matter and make $w_{\epsilon}$ be not differentiable at $y$. Thanks for the further clarification.